# Converting a Rails 3 application to use jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to covert a RAILS 3 project to use jquery.

I am using:

```
rake rails:template LOCATION=http://github.com/lleger/Rails-3-jQuery/raw/master/jquery.rb
```

as suggested https://github.com/lleger/Rails-3-jQuery

However, I am getting some error. With trace enabled, I get the following:

```
** Invoke rails:template (first_time)
** Execute rails:template
rake aborted!
redirection forbidden: http://github.com/lleger/Rails-3-jQuery/raw/master/jquery.rb -> https://github.com/lleger/Rails-3-jQuery/raw/master/jquery.rb
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:174:in `open_loop'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:132:in `open_uri'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:518:in `open'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:30:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions.rb:212:in `apply'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/tasks/framework.rake:30
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

What can be the possible reason and How do i get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing http to https in the LOCATION link. The log is saying that GitHub is trying to redirect to the https version

```
redirection forbidden: http://github.com/lleger/Rails-3-jQuery/raw/master/jquery.rb -> https://github.com/lleger/Rails-3-jQuery/raw/master/jquery.rb
```